# jQuery return all page disabled and then enable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like a simple method to set the enteir page disabled (links,buttons etc ... all disabled) then i need to be able to re-enable all in the page.

is there a light way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option that is obvious for me is to set the "cover" layer:

```
<div id="cover"></div>
```

With style:

```
#cover {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100000;
}
```

If you need to disable everything, just make it visible with `show` method.

```
$("#cover").show();
```

It will work like this: http://jsfiddle.net/KEAh8/

Comment: make sure you set a high z-index on it, so it covers everything

Comment: @PitaJ Yes, it is set in the answer but not in the demo.

Comment: is it possible to declair this into a global funct which takes all ajax request i've just implemented?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you can use `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` events. Just add `show()` on `ajaxStart` and `hide` on `ajaxStop`, and you will get great result :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a light-weight method since it will have to scan the DOM to find every element, but it will work:

```
$("input, select, button, textarea").attr("disabled", true);
```

It depends on the size of your page to know if this is a good approach, and the selector could change depending on content. Reverse the attribute setting to enable everything again.

Edit:

As Porco pointed out, to disable the anchor tags you must prevent the default action, so add something like this:

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: For disabling input elements it is better to use `prop("disabled", true)`. And there is the same problem with anchor tag `click` event as in @Porco answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$('*').attr('disabled', 'disabled').addClass('disabled')
```

So now we've disabled all inputs and added 'disabled' class to everything. Now we just want to disable links, I think this should work:

```
$('body').on('click', '.disabled', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```

To renable everything simply:

```
$('*').attr('disabled', '').removeClass('disabled')
```

Comment: `click` disabler won't work if you have bound the handler beforehand.